# Calibrating Generalized Hyperbolic distribution in R - which parameters are valid and allow for a numerical calculation of absolute moments

Tags: maximum-likelihood, optimization, parameterization

I am using the R-package `ghyp` in order to calibrate and model. In fact my coding is based on this [paper](http://www.skokholm.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/UAR.pdf).

I know that I could do quite a robust fit using `fit.ghypuv` but I try to maximize a rather complicated likelihood function bases on a Markov-chain with ghyp marginals given the state. 
Therefore I use a non-linear optimizer (`nloptr` with parameter NLOPT_LN_NELDERMEAD and `optim` with parameter Nelder-Mead).

In the alpha-bar parametrization I assure that $\bar{\alpha}$ and $\sigma$ are great zero. Do I have to restrict the parameters further? If yes, then how can I do this? I use $\log$ and $\exp$ transformations to transform the non-negative parameters to the real line and some $(0,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ mapping for the probabilities of the chain.

Part of the calibration is based on absolute centered moments of the ghyp distribution. These are calculated numerically using `ghyp.moment`.
The problem is that the optimizer searches the whole space (it searches in $\mathbb{R}$ and in the objective function I transform the parameters to their domain, i.e. probabilities to $(0,1)$ and non-negative parameters to $\mathbb{R}^+$) and finds values such that I get the error message

```
Error in integrate(internal.moment, -Inf, Inf, tmp.order = order[i], 
lambda = object@lambda,  :  the integral is probably divergent
```

E.g. I get the error in this parameter setting:

```
my.ghyp =ghyp(lambda = -1.570151, mu =  0.006935, sigma = 0.001719412, 
              gamma = -0.006574129, alpha.bar = 923391)
ghyp.moment(my.ghyp,order=1,absolute=TRUE,central=TRUE)
```

while it works, if I increase $\sigma$ slightly

```
my.ghyp =ghyp(lambda = -1.570151, mu =  0.006935, sigma = 0.003, 
              gamma = -0.006574129, alpha.bar = 923391)
ghyp.moment(my.ghyp,order=1,absolute=TRUE,central=TRUE)
```

EDIT: In the paper mentioned the absolute moments of $X$, ie. $|X|$, is used for the calibration for $X\sim \text{GHYP}$. This has to be done numerically. If I reformulate the calibration using $X^2$ can I then avoid a numerical procedure and get something explicite or some recursion?

EDIT: I have found the paper [Moments of the generalized hyperbolic distribution](http://mpra.ub.uni-muenchen.de/19081/). There one can find expressions using fractions of Bessel functions that can be calculated in a nummerically stable way for moments up to order four. I will use this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No additional constraints are needed for the moments to exist.  Most likely you are running into numerical inaccuracies in the implementation of `ghyp.moment`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe you can help me solve the problem. I edited the question and added:In the paper mentioned the absolute moment of $X$, ie. $|X|$, is used for the calibration for $X\sim \text{GHYP}$. This has to be done numerically. If I reformulate the calibration using $X^2$ can I then avoid a numerical procedure and get something explicite or some recursion?